# Capture and log the api calls made to the server along with the passed data and the results

Tags: node.js

I have an api written in node.js that handles calls coming in from websites, desktop applications, iOS applications etc. There are probably 50+ endpoints and each end point can accept anywhere from 1 parameter to possibly 10-20 depending on what is intendeding to be accomplished. These can be GET/POST/PUT/DEL

I want to start load testing my API and simulating users activities.

What I am looking for is suggestions on how you can capture the API call and the parameters that were passed along with it in a logical way.

I use forever to run my app and everything is written to a log file so my initial reaction was to do something like add a piece of middleware to the express routes that would capture the endpoint as well as the req.params and req.body but then I need to put this middleware in all 50+ routes kind of tedious.

Anyone done something like this before and has a good idea on how to capture calls / data with those calls as well as possibly capturing what is returned from my API.

Perhaps some module?

I need to have this in a readable format to provide to other people so they can structure a fake set of calls... so raw log files aren't really helpful unless they are outputted.... "pretty".

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track – just add your logger middleware via [`app.use`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use), which runs the middleware on every request (rather than adding it to each route).

In fact, the Express docs give an example of using logger middleware:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// simple logger
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log('%s %s', req.method, req.url);
  next();
});
```

Connect (on which Express is built) provides [logger middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-logger.html), so you can just do:

```
var logFile = fs.createWriteStream('./myLogFile.log', {flags: 'a'});    
app.use(express.logger({stream: logFile}));
```

Comment: Oh wow this looks like it should be easier than I had originally thought. I think I was over complicating it.